# About adverbial phrase

Tags: grammar, adverbial-phrases

> "She is at the point of her death."

Here, 'at the point of her death' is said to be an adverbial phrase by the textbook which modifies the finite verb 'is'. But I thought it is an adjective phrase modifying the subject 'she'. If I am wrong, where and how?

Comment: I agree with you--it's a preposition phrase acting as an 'adjectival' predicate complement. But we don't say that a person is 'at the point of' somebody **else's** death!

Comment: oops... I edited that...

Comment: A complement, yes, but locative not predicative.

Comment: What if she's at wit's end?   Is the type of complement determined semantically or naively (in the algorithmic sense)?

Comment: @StoneyB  I'm curious, though.  If it's adjectival then we should be able to use it as an adjective, "At the point of her death she is calm".  Here it *seems* more like an adverbial phrase telling us the time frame, and not describing her.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "**She is at the point of her death.**" has a subject, a verb, and an adverbial prepositional phrase.

- [She] [is] [at the point of her death].

Here the "**Adverbial Prepositional Phrase**" modifies the verb "**is**" and answers the questions "**Where?**", "**At what point?**", or even "**When?**". Here "**at**" is the head of the phrase and "**the point of her death**" is a noun phrase functioning as a prepositional complement.

Comment: I don't think it's an adverbial prepositional phrase, Alex, because "is" is a copula or linking verb; therefore, it's not modifying the verb "is"; it's complementing it.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola Are you sure? It doesn't make sense as anything other than an adverbial phrase. It does answer the question, "**Where?**" maybe "**When?**" doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but as Stoney B points out above, I think it is a predicate complement. If it were, "She writhed on her bed *at the point of her death*", I would agree with you because it would be acting as if it were and adverb, modifying "writhed".

Comment: Adverbs and adjectives and their complements and adjuncts and phrases are not my strong suit, so I shall defer to you on this one, but Stoney B suggests that it is a predicate complement and that is what I think it is, but I'm not sure. I don't like the word *adverbial* here because "is" is a linking verb; therefore, it never takes an adverb--only an adjective: "She is independent"--not "She is independently."

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola Hmm, taking that into account you may be right.

Comment: Yeah, with most verbs except linking verbs, I would absolutely agree with you. I just don't think it's correct in this instance with a linking verb because "is" doesn't take an adverb ever. I think we get the point of your post. It works with almost any other verb and would be correct. I'm also not 100% sure as this is not my best topic. Also, would you go under the question, "Does the past perfect tense make sense in this sentence?" that was asked earlier, read my answers, and upvote mine and downvote the others that are wrong? Read mine. You'll agree, I think.

Comment: @Nick I agree with you. This can never be adverbial. It may answer the question where and when but not in relation to a verb. It is a predicate complement. A is B, one of the simplest in English in fact.

Comment: Do you know what, Lambie? After looking at it again, I'm going to say Alex (SovereignSun) is right: *it is an adverbial prepositional phrase*, but it's also a predicate complement in my mind. See http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/prepphrases/. **Chicago is on the northeast tip of Illinois.** *("on the northeast tip" modifies "is"; "of Illinois" modifies "tip.")*

Comment: I'm also not sure though that I agree with that site because it could be written, "Chicago is **a city** *on the northeast tip of Illinois*," in which case, I believe "on the northeast tip of Illinois" is now modifying the predicate complement "a city"; therefore, I'm not so sure that that website is correct. I think the prepositional phrase is really modifying an implicit predicate complement there rather than "is". Either way, I've upvoted Alex because I think this one is very difficult. Even in Alex's example, it still is "A is B" and that's a complement in my mind and an adjective.

Comment: @Nick.. I've studied [Thoughtco](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-predicate-1691010) and [Predicate Complements by Frank Van Eynde](http://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/HPSG/2008/vaneynde.pdf) and "**at the point of her death**" doesn't look much like a predicate compliment but it might be because the grammar around predicates is very vague.

Comment: Well, I have voted you up because I think it's a tough one and, whether you be right or wrong, it was an admirable answer!